# Render image path to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a weird bug that just happened to me, it was working before but I changed something very small that broke everything.

So, I have an Image that I find in the DB and then render it to the view by building the image link. The thing is : Razor is unable to map it to the image.

I have made an mage to show you how weird it is.

[image]

As you can see, those are the exact same strings, one is mapped correctly, the other isn't. I wonder is there is some kind of format that I'm missing. If I do "Server.MapPath" to get the absolute path of the Image, then it maps it correctly but the access to the image is forbidden (because absolute path).

Comment: I'd post real markup rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Markup ? What do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor is only applying this tilde-slash magic when the relative path is applied directly into some HTML element's attribute, not when it's part of some model property.

You'll have to use `Url.Content` explicitly:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ProfilePicturePath)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use custom htmlhelper of image and use  like this.
@html.Image(@item.ImageName)